# How to style a class based component on react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

Ive been looking for styling guides for react-admin, using material-ui. But I could not find an example on how it is done for class based components.

I hope someone shares their knowledge.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Requests for a guide, book, etc. are off-topic for stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

user2002500. I hope this can help you.

1st, u need to import wtihStyles

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

2nd, create a variable above class

```
const styles = {
field: {
 widht: '80%' }
}

class Test extends Component {
....
}
```

3rd, add {...this.props} to a component you want to style

```
<TextField source= "id" {...this.props}/>
```

4th, add withStyles when export default

```
export default withStyles(styles)(Test)
```

5th, destructuring classes from this.props

```
render() {
const { classes } = this.props
 return( 
 ....
 )
}
```

6th, last finishing back to the component you have add {...this.props},
add className property with classes.image

```
<TextField source= "id" className={classes.field} {...this.props}/>
```

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { TextField, Edit, SimpleForm } from 'react-admin';

const styles = {
field: {
 widht: '80%' }
}

class Test extends Component {
 render() {
 const { classes } = this.props
  return (
  <Edit title={'Test'} {...this.props}>
   <SimpleForm>
    <TextField source= "id" className={classes.field} {...this.props}/> 
   </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>

  );
 }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Test)
```

maybe, this not a good explanation. But i think this the right step if you want use class component then function component.